# Is there any complex integral that is singular and cannot be solved using residue theorems?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

Is there any complex integral whose denominator vanishes at some points in the complex plane(while the numerator does not) and cannot be solved using residue theorems?